# PHP entity class example

Tags: php, model-view-controller, entity

I've been trying to find an example of an entity class, to make sure what i should put in it. Could someone give med an example of how such a class would look like?

1. Should this object only contain data, like I could simply use an StdClass-object? 
   Or should it contain my CRUD-methods too? (Create, Read, Update, Delete)
2. Would it be a good approach to create an instance of my entity class, for each row in my database or model, or should I use use one entity-class and save all the different rows in an array-property of the entity class?

Comment: MVC is probably a better approach for what you're trying to do. Have a look at [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), it's a very poweful, MVC structured framework.

Comment: @Sune, it depend on what your exact goal is. I tend to use [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject), which are populated by custom-written [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html). And you really should not mix the entities with the persistence logic, otherwise you end up with [active record](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) anti pattern.

Answer (score 1):

In my last project I separated **Entity** and **Mapper** (CRUD actions) so it looks like this:

**Entity**

```
Class PostEntity
{
    public $title;
    public $text;
}
```

**Mapper**

```
Class PostMapper
{
    public function load($id)
    {
        // load one record from Database where id = $id
    }

    public function save()
    {
        // insert new record or edit in Database
    }

    public function delete()
    {
        // delete from Database
    }
}
```

**Usage - 1 Entity**

```
$postMapper = new PostMapper();
$post = $postMapper->load(1); // load from Database where post_id = 1
$post->title = "New title"; // set new post title
$postMapper->save($post); // edit post in Database
```

**Usage - Multiple Entities**

```
$postMapper = new PostMapper();
$posts = $postMapper->loadAllFromCategory(2); // load from Database where cateogory_id = 1
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "<h3>" . $post->title . "</h3>";
}
```

So, in my example **Entity** is "stupid" collection of variables (columns from database table) and setters/getters (optional) while **Mapper** do all the database work (**CRUD**). If I want to change mapper to get results from external XML I just create **PostMapperXml** class to load data from XML.

Answer (score 0):

As a commenter has noted using a MVC framework would be the best way to ease into things. Or ad list using Doctrine2 - an ORM (it maps PHP classes to database tables and does all the querying for you).

But to answer your questiosn:

1. It should be a different class for each entity (table). It should contian *ad list* CRUD methods, but can contain other data related methods (An "Article" entity could contain getBodyLinks() method that would parse the body and return all urls.
2. Each entity is ... well one entity. If you for some reason don't want loads of object instances floating around you should be going more "low level" than entity.

Symfony2 + Doctrine2 example:

https://github.com/stfalcon/BlogBundle/blob/master/Entity/Post.php

(this is just some random repo I found on github)